# How to find strongest path between two nodes in a directed graph in matlab or ucinet?

Tags: matlab, graph, graph-theory

Suppose the matrix below as a directed graph adjacency matrix with 3 nodes.

```
A=[.35 .076 .12;.0054 .83 .09; .31 .92 .019]
```

How can I find the strongest path between two specific nodes in matlab or ucinet?

I need some way to tell matlab that find every possible paths between two nodes, then sum up the weights of edges in each path and find the maximum weighted path, then show that path. 
For example if we consider marix A and want to find the strongest path from node 1 to node 3, we have two possible paths: one direct path from node 1 to node 3 and one path from node 1 to node 2 and node 2 to node 3. in the first path we have A(1,3)=.12 and for second path we have A(1,2)+ A(2,3)= .076+.09=.166, so the second path is strongest path from node 1 to node 3, and we have it as 1-2-3. Is there any way to do something like this in matlab or ucinet?

Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To find strongest path between two nodes in a directed graph in MATLAB, you can use [`Graph::longestPath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/graph-longestpath.html) in the Symbolic Math Toolbox (note that the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path [`graphshortestpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphshortestpath.html) is in the Bioinformatics Toolbox)

Comment: Note that it is necessary for the graph to be directed acyclic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), otherwise there could be a path with infinite weight.